# Uploading files using jQuery drag&drop in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, drag-and-drop

I have little (almost no) experience with AJAX.

I want to create a sample form where I can upload image files (think about eBay auctions), but these files can (and should) be dragged&dropped into the browser window like when you upload an APK to Google Play.

I haven't done such a thing ever, and I want to learn. I *currently* don't have a real use case to implement, I'm asking this to **learn**. So, let's pick the eBay example.

My ViewModel may look like the following:

```
public class AuctionViewModel {

    public string Title, Description;
    public double Price;
    [...]
    public IEnumerable<Picture> Images; //most important part!
}

public class Picture {
    public string Url; //display URL, perhaps to be generated
    public byte[] payload; //uploaded data
}
```

Points of the question:

1. How does the controller look like? I think I need a separate controller for AJAX uploading (the ViewModel is supposed to be stored in the Session)
2. How does the Javascript client-side code look like?
3. Is there any tutorial about draggable&droppable files in jQuery/AJAX/MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). It would allow you to subscribe to the `drop` event of a DOM element and be able to retrieve the file contents and use the XmlHTTPRequest object to asynchronously send the file to the server. The Mozilla link I have posted contains extensive examples.

On the server side you might consider using an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` for the uploaded files payload instead of a `byte[]`. If you use `multipart/form-data` content type with the AJAX request as shown in the examples the default model binder will automatically bind the uploaded files to the model.